# How Can I Click a card with protractor using class name

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to click at the first card at my page, which has the classe card card-convite. I'm trying using:

```
element(by.css('card card-convite')).click();
```

and

```
element(by.className('card card-convite')).click();
```

but protractor keeps me returning the error:

> Failed: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

**MY HTML**

```
<app-lista-pessoas-pesquisadas _ngcontent-c23="" _nghost-c27=""> 
<div _ngcontent-c27="" class="card card-convite"> 
<div _ngcontent-c27="" class="header"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with following line:

```
element(by.css('.card-convite')).click();
```

You should not forget the starting **.** (dot) of a class.

Or otherwise if you want to use multiple classes, you can do this:

`element(by.css('.card.card-convite')).click()`